# split certain parts of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a method that returns a String from a [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org/) scrape, something along the line of this:

```
New York Aer Lingus EI104 23 Feb 05:15
```

Firstly, I want to be able to format the string into something like this:

```
AerLingus From: New York  No: EI104 Time: 23 Feb 05:15 Status: Arrived
```

As it stands I use a string split and split each word into an element in an array. Trouble is, some airlines are two names, and some are one, as with some departure names. If this was fixed all the time I could concat some elements together and leave it at that, but as it stands the number of elements going into the array is dynamic.

How can I split some elements of the string into an array element and not others? Is there a way to do this?

I want to be able to say that New York is one element and Aer Lingus is one element and so on......

```
public ArrayList<ArrivalDetails> process() throws IOException{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements tableRow = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for(Element tr : tableRow){
        if(tr.text().contains(airline)){
            if(tr.text().contains("Arrived")){
            String delims = "[ ]+";
            String[] singleRowArray = tr.text().split(delims);
            ArrivalDetails temp = new ArrivalDetails(singleRowArray);
            capture.add(temp);
            }
        }

    }
    testPrint();
    return capture;
}

public static void testPrint(){
    System.out.println("====================TEST=======================");
    System.out.println(capture.get(capture.size()-8));
    System.out.println("================END TEST=======================");
}
```

My other Class

```
public class ArrivalDetails {
    String origin;
    String airline1;
    String airline2;
    String flightNo;
    String date;
    String month;
    String arrTime;
    String status;


    public ArrivalDetails(String[] singleRowArray) {
        this.origin = singleRowArray[0];
        this.airline1 = singleRowArray[1];
        this.airline2 = singleRowArray[2];
        this.flightNo = singleRowArray[3];
        this.date = singleRowArray[4];
        this.month = singleRowArray[5];
        this.arrTime = singleRowArray[6];
        this.status = singleRowArray[7];

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String airline = airline1.concat(airline2);
        return airline1 + airline2 + " From: " + origin + " " + " No: " + flightNo + "        Time: "+date+" "+month+" "+arrTime +" Status: "+ status ;
    }

    }
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: As the string has no guarantees about `Aer Lingus` or `New York` having characteristic sizes, there is no single way to always get the correct split without the function having prescience, i.e., a list of known word splits.

Comment: How do you plan on knowing if "New York American" is destination "New" with airline "York American" or "New York" with airline "American"? I haven't worked with JSoup but you should see if you can add a delimiter after each "real" token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only **safe option** is to have a list of the airlines and the cities, or at the very least the airlines and use the position of that string inside your main string as the divider for the rest. Since they all seem to follow the same pattern, `CITY AIRLINE FLIGHTN DATE`

Comment: That being the case, an airline list would be easy enough to conjure up. Would an array be the best method to store the list? How would I go about coding it if I'm using the airline and not splitting the string before hand. I'm new to Java and learning as I go here.